# Selenium Python .click() not working on one element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So, I am trying to make a simple project that simply just auto clicks all the details to fill out a form to get ready to post.  It works perfectly up until just one element.  There are 2 very similar elements; ones a category and the other is a sub-category.  It states its unable to find the element, I'm fairly new to selenium so if anyone has an opinions they can give me that would be very helpful.  I tried a few other methods too, using different identifiers, like its class.

```
from msilib.schema import Condition
from tokenize import Name
from turtle import color
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.grailed.com/sell")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div[7]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/p[2]/a').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div[7]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button[4]').click()
google_email = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="email"]')
google_email.send_keys("@gmail.com")
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="password"]').send_keys('')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div[7]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/button').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="SellForm"]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/input').click()
time.sleep(2)
#Start of entering clothing details
#picking type of clothing, men or woman
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="SellForm"]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span[1]').click()
time.sleep(2)
#selects the main category
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="SellForm"]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span[2]').click()
time.sleep(2)
something = 'something'
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="designer-autocomplete"]').send_keys(something)
time.sleep(1)


#picking the sub-category, but this not working for some reason
#Error states unable to locate element
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="SellForm"]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/input').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="SellForm"]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/span[4]').click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code as below, try this:

```
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div[7]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/p[2]/a').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div[7]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button[4]').click()
google_email = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="email"]')
google_email.send_keys("argelarroyo2001@gmail.com")
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="password"]').send_keys('Pineappleguy305')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div[7]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/button').click()
time.sleep(3)

title = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".SellFormHeader-Title")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)",title)

driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="SellForm"]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/input').click()
time.sleep(2)
#Start of entering clothing details
#picking type of clothing, men or woman
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="SellForm"]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span[1]').click()
time.sleep(2)
#selects the main category
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="SellForm"]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span[2]').click()
time.sleep(2)

# Sub-category field
sub_category_option = "Tank Tops & Sleeveless"
sub_category_lists = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*[@class='CustomDropDown-module__dropDownItems___7n7Mi']/span")
i = 0
for x in sub_category_lists:
    if x.text == sub_category_option:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@class='CustomDropDown-module__dropDownItems___7n7Mi']/span[" + str(i + 1) + "]").click()
        break
    i += 1

# Designer field
option_to_select = 'Advisry Clothing'  # change the option you want to select
designer_txt_field = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="designer-autocomplete"]')
designer_txt_field.click()
designer_txt_field.send_keys("Ad")  # you have to enter some character to search and select the value of the string 'option_to_select'
time.sleep(1)

option_list = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".Designer-module__autocomplete___fCmzc li")
time.sleep(1)

i = 0
for x in option_list:
    if x.text == option_to_select:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@class='Designer-module__autocomplete___fCmzc']/li[" + str(i + 1) + "]").click()
        break
    i += 1
```

Comment: for some reason it clicks and send keys to every other option, but for sub-category it just is always skipping it and not clicking anything for it.

Comment: Your question is to select any option from 'Designer' auto-suggestion drop down right?

Comment: no specifically its to choose the subcategory section, then from there to choose the size, but when i use the same method i used for the category it doesn't select it for some reason.  So, I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: I updated the code to select an option from the sub-category field, check it.

Comment: Ok just tried the code and it worked.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok I see what you did there.  You searched directly for the text in the element that contained all the options.  What do you recommend for the size option?  It doesn't interact like the other elements such as the the category and sub-category.  Those size options can't be inspected.

Comment: To get the size, you have to use 'len()' function.

Comment: If this answer works for you Accept this as the answer.